# Determining the factor between the main currency unit and the fractional unit

Tags: c#, .net, currency

According to [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency):

> Each currency typically has a main currency unit (the dollar, for example, or the euro) and a fractional unit, **often defined as ​1⁄100 of the main unit**: 100 cents = 1 dollar, 100 centimes = 1 franc, 100 pence = 1 pound, **although units of ​1⁄10 or ​1⁄1000 occasionally also occur.** Some currencies do not have any smaller units at all, such as the Icelandic króna.

So it is obviously not always correct just to divide by 100.

Does `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits` represent the actual factor between the main currency unit and the fractional unit? Or is it just for representation?

So when I work with values that are supposed to represent the fractional unit, can I calculate the main currency by doing something like

```
mainCurrencyUnit = amountAsFractionalCurrencyUnit / Math.Pow(10, CurrencyDecimalDigits);
```

Or what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at this library https://github.com/remyvd/NodaMoney `NumberFormatInfo` is used to format numbers/currency according to system/culture settings, imho

Comment: Some currencies have a factor which is not a *power of 10*, e.g. Mauritanian Ouguiya (factor is `1/5`)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217